# How to refresh android listview in its adpter

Tags: android, listview, refresh, broadcast

I put a button in a listview item, the onclicklistener was set in the getView() method of the adpter. The adapter is an individual class file extends BaseAdapter. And by the onclick event of the button, the data set of the  listview is changed, how can I refresh the listview in the adapter?

I can not call adpter.notifyDataSetChanged() method in the getView() method of the adapter.

And now I am using broadcast to notify the listview in ***Activity.class. However, I dont think it is a good idea. Then, how to make it?

Comment: Let your Adapter implement `View.OnClickListener` and then you just need to assign listener to your button with `button.setOnClickListener(this)` and then in your `onClick()` method you can simply call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `I can not call adpter.notifyDataSetChanged() method in the getView() method of the adapter.` why not ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make it clear. Actually, the problem is I start a download thread in the onClidk() method. The listview should be refreshed after the download completed. Unfortunately, the download thread is another individual class file. And now, I am trying to parse the adapter instance into the constructor of the Download thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add something like

```
AdapterClass.this.notifyDataSetchanged()
```

to your onClickListener within the getView() method?

Comment: Thank U. I parsed the AdapterClass.this as the parameter of the constructor method in Downloader class. And it works.